# Apparmor denies access to my public key

Tags: permissions, ssh, 18.04, apparmor

I can't fetch any repositories due to apparmor denies access to my public key located in my home folder. How can i enable access to this file?

Logs:

```
 Jul 18 08:55:01 PC-NAME kernel: [33629.897509] audit: type=1400 audit(1531896901.894:10573): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gitkraken.gitkraken" name="/etc/" pid=14984 comm="sh" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0

 Jul 18 08:55:02 PC-NAME kernel: [33630.304531] audit: type=1400 audit(1531896902.298:10574): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gitkraken.gitkraken" name="/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" pid=5405 comm="gitkraken" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000

 Jul 18 08:56:01 PC-NAME kernel: [33689.859314] audit: type=1400 audit(1531896961.854:10575): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gitkraken.gitkraken" name="/etc/" pid=15027 comm="sh" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0

 Jul 18 08:56:02 PC-NAME kernel: [33690.270418] audit: type=1400 audit(1531896962.270:10576): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gitkraken.gitkraken" name="/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" pid=5405 comm="gitkraken" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so i have just found i need to run this command:

```
snap connect gitkraken:ssh-keys
```